# How to retrieve H2O model from mojo zip file?

Tags: python, h2o, mojo

I saved H2O model using `model.download_mojo(path="path", get_genmodel_jar=True)`.
I want retrieve that model to use in jupyter notebook again.
How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
data = h2o.import_file(path='training_dataset.csv')
original_model = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator()
original_model.train(x = ["Some column", "Another column"], y = "response", training_frame=data)

path = '/path/to/model/directory/model.zip'
original_model.download_mojo(path)
```

And then in a new notebook do this:

```
path = '/path/to/model/directory/model.zip'
imported_model = h2o.import_mojo(path)
new_observations = h2o.import_file(path='new_observations.csv')
predictions = imported_model.predict(new_observations)
```

[ Taken from this page in the documentation:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/mojo_import.html ]

Comment: Thank you TomKraljevic, I could import the model, but this was a random forest model. Later I am passing this model to H2OTree method. But I get an error that this is not a tree based model. I think it gets imported as MOJO model. Is there any way to import tree based model.

Comment: Instead of exporting a MOJO, you can call saveModel and loadModel.  But the H2O-3 software version number needs to be the same.

Comment: Yes, but this model was exported as mojo in past.